# Сформулировать регулярное выражение для запроса

Tags: регулярные-выражения, elasticsearch

Мне нужно искать в текстах выражения вида "объект 11/23"
Пытаюсь:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
{
   "query" : {
        "regexp":{
            "content": "[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}"
    }
},
"_source": ["_id", "filename", "tags"],
"from": 0,
"size": 100,
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
        "content": {  }
    }
}
}'
```

Не ищет.
При этом

```
"content": "[0-9]{2}"
```

работает - находит все двузначные числа, а

```
"content": "объект [0-9]{2}"
```

не работает, и

```
"content": "объект\\ "
```

не работает. В общем "всё делаю правильно, но ничего не работает", как правильно использовать спецсимволы?

Answer (score 1):

Позволю себе длинную цитату.
Есть файл, который проиндексирован и ищется, например, так:

```
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]# curl -XPOST "http : //localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
    > {
    >    "query" : {
    >         "regexp":{
    >             "content": "dormidontus"
    >     }
    > },
    > "_source": ["_id", "filename", "tags"],
    > "from": 0,
    > "size": 100,
    > "highlight": {
    >     "fields": {
    >         "content": {  }
    >     }
    > }
    > }'
    {"took":9,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"3click","_type":"text","_id":"AVM2oBZ8xMlZ32JDAYnk","_score":1.0,"_source":{"filename":"/home/avoiteh/mtest/новый текст.txt","tags":"test,дед_мороз"},"highlight":{"content":[" 1/2  <em>dormidontus</em> 11/23 upsum lorem  в лесу родилась ёлочка в лесу она росла зимой и летом стройная зелёная была метель её пела песенки спи ёлочка бай-бай "]}}]}}[root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
```

Видно, что в тексте содержится 11/23.
По "content": "23" - тоже ищется правильно.
НО:

```
[root@clientlan-1-110 html]# curl -XPOST "http : //localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
    > {
    >    "query" : {
    >         "regexp":{
    >             "content": "[0-9]/[0-9]"
    >     }
    > },
    > "_source": ["_id", "filename", "tags"],
    > "from": 0,
    > "size": 100,
    > "highlight": {
    >     "fields": {
    >         "content": {  }
    >     }
    > }
    > }'
    {"took":18,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}[root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]# curl -XPOST "http : //localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
    > {
    >    "query" : {
    >         "regexp":{
    >             "content": "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"
    >     }
    > },
    > "_source": ["_id", "filename", "tags"],
    > "from": 0,
    > "size": 100,
    > "highlight": {
    >     "fields": {
    >         "content": {  }
    >     }
    > }
    > }'
    {"took":23,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}[root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]# curl -XPOST "http : //localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
    > {
    >    "query" : {
    >         "regexp":{
    >             "content": "[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}"
    >     }
    > },
    > "_source": ["_id", "filename", "tags"],
    > "from": 0,
    > "size": 100,
    > "highlight": {
    >     "fields": {
    >         "content": {  }
    >     }
    > }
    > }'
    {"took":22,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}[root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]# curl -XPOST "http : //localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
    > {
    >    "query" : {
    >         "regexp":{
    >             "content": "[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}"
}
    >     }
    > },
    > "_source": ["_id", "filename", "tags"],
    > "from": 0,
    > "size": 100,
    > "highlight": {
    >     "fields": {
    >         "content": {  }
    >     }
    > }
    > }'
    {"took":25,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}[root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
    [root@clientlan-1-110 html]#
```

Как видно - ничего не находит. Что-то я со слешами косячу, но не могу понять что :(

Answer (score 0):

Замените двойной обратный слэш на одинарный.

Comment: не помогает. Причём даже если прямо задаю выражение "content" : "11\/23" или "11/23" regex`пом не ищет, а "match_phrase" - ищет. И regexp нормально работает если не пытаюсь искать что-то с пробелом или слешами :(

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет. Для использования слэша в регулярном выражении его нужно экранировать обратным слэшем.

Answer (score 0):

Решение не акти какое, но можно сделать [0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}
т.е. / как просто символ искать...

Comment: Увы :( Результат точно тот же. Опробовал [/] [\/] [\\/] найдено 0 :(
Более того, я пробовал: "content": "/", "content": "\/", "content": "\\/", "content": "[/]", "content": "[\/]", "content": "[\\/]" - просто один символ найти. Народная индейская изба...